# Equations relevant to gravity powered clocks and machines such as the gravity light

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, energy-efficiency

What equations are needed to describe the forces and properties of the kind of mechanisms used in a machine that harnesses the gravitational potential energy of a suspended weight to rotate the shaft of a permanent magnet DC generator (i.e. the [gravity light](http://gravitylight.org))?

Basically, these machines aim to slow the descent of a suspended weight and convert that slow downward motion into high rpm rotary motion that is used to do work. As far as I can tell, this slowdown can be achieved using some kind of governor (in the case of a gravity powered clock air resistance from some spinning baffles is utilized), or by the torque required to turn the shaft on the generator.

How can the relationship between the mass of the weight, the torque required to turn the generator, and/or any gearing that might be helpful be described mathematically?

Comment: Energy available = mass x height x g = kg x metres x 9.8 Joule. Power = energy/tine to change Watts = m x h /(9.8 x t_seconds). All at 100% efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the force exerted by the mass and converting it to rotational force or torque will involve the following equations:

F = g*(mass) where g = 9.81 and
T = r*F where r is the radius of the pulley from which the suspended mass is hanging. This is the torque that turns the generator.

When other factors such as gears are included the gear ratios need to be multiplied with the torque. Example equations can be seen below:

gear 1 radius is 20
gear 2 radius is 10
if the Torque in the shaft of gear 1 is 5 N.m then the torque in gear shaft 2 is:
T2 = 10/20*T1 = 2.5 N.m.
Gear calculations can become more complicated with modulus and gear teeth etc being included but this is the basics of it.